# page not found 404 django - Login Page

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to login using username and password, On clicking the login button it should redirect to the homepage.html, But i am getting page not found error 404. please help me out.

I have posted urls.py, views.py and html tag related to this question below. Please let me know if you need any more details

```
#urls.py 

from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_view

urlpatterns = [


    path('', views.login, name='login_page'),
    path('/login_validation/', views.login_validation, name="login_validation"),

    #path('login/', auth_view.LoginView.as_view(template_name='templates/login.html'), name='login'),
    #path('logout/', auth_view.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='templates/logout.html'), name='logout'),
]



#views.py


from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, auth
from django.contrib import messages

def login(request):
    return render(request, "login.html")

def login_validation(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        username=request.POST("username")
        password=request.POST("password")
        user=auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request, user)
            return render(request, "homepage.html")
        else:
            return render(request, "login.html")

    else:
        return render(request, "login.html")


login.html
    
 <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
 <center> <a id="btn-login" type ="submit" href="{% url 'login_validation' %}" class="btn btn-success">Login  </a></center>
    
 </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried removing slash from `path('/login_validation/', views.login_validation, name="login_validation"),` ?

Comment: yes...but no use

Comment: hey now atleast my code is getting connected..but post request is not getting sent on button click

Comment: I suggest you using this tutorlal https://wsvincent.com/django-user-authentication-tutorial-login-and-logout/

Comment: sure will check it

Answer (score 0):

Add home url in **urls.py**:

```
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
path('home', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html'), name='home'),
```

Comment: i got the solution it was mistake with some other part of the code

Comment: where is mistake ??